# VueJS Translate Plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, translate

I am using a plugin called VueTranslated, made by javisperez and I am having some difficulty to get the translated text.

I am using the globally usage. I have a file that has all the words and their translations, like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTranslate from 'vue-translate-plugin'
Vue.use(VueTranslate)

Vue.locales({
  'pt_BR': {
    'hello-world': 'Olá mundo'
  },
  'en_US': {
    'hello-world': 'Hello world'
  }
})
```

export default()

So, when I am in any component, I can get the words using something like:

```
<template>
<div>
    <p> {{t('hello-world)}} </p>
</div>
</template>
```

Then, the `p` tag shows me the string `Hello world` or `Olá mundo` depending of my language set.
But if I have, in this component, something like

```
<template>
<div>
    <p> {{message}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            message: this.$translate.text('hello-world)
        })
    }
</script>
```

it just appear `hello-world` in my `p` tag.
How can I get a translated string when it comes from the script tag of my component?
Or, do I have anything else to try instead of this plugin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrow function to return your data and use `locale` property instead of `text`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: this.$translate.locale['hello-world']
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$translate.setLang('pt_BR')
  },
  locales: {
    pt_BR: {
      'hello-world': 'Olá mundo'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-translate-plugin@1.2.0/dist/vue-translate.common.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p> {{ message }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still getting "Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'locale' of undefined" "

Comment: @LeonardoSantos: In you main.js define your locales without quotes (`pt_BR: { 'hello-world': 'Olá mundo' }` not `'pt_BR'`). Then in your `new Vue({...})` add a created hook where you define your locale: `created() { 
    this.$translate.setLang('pt_BR');
  }` [Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2owk7y07nj)

Comment: thanks for trying to help! But it didn't work yet. I tried removing the quotes but it didn't cause any change. I wish I could pass the translated strings to my component data or component props but I still couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to use `this.t('message')` like:

```
<script>

export default {
    data {
        return {
            message: this.t('message')
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: It should be corrected like this with '$',

<script>

export default {
    data {
        return {
            message: this.$t('message')
        }
    }
}

</script>

Answer (score 0):

It should be corrected like this with '$',

```
export default {
data {
    return {
        message: this.$t('message')
    }
}
```

}